# Clean NSLog - No timestamp and program name

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, nslog

I almost finishing a clean NSLog with this code:

```
#define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, __VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

This work fine if I do this:

```
 NSLog(@"Show %@ message", @"this");
```

But, will fail if I user it

```
 NSLog(@"One argument");
```

because `__VA_ARGS__` is nothing, so it produce

```
 printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"One argument",] UTF8String]);
```

So, the problem is the comma. Because this is macro, `__VA_ARGS__` is nothing. So I can't do things like `__VA_ARGS__==nil` because will produce `==nil` and will fail.

The question is simple: What to do when `__VA_ARGS__` is nothing? Or only use comma when have more arguments.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use this code (notice the `##` part):

```
#define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

Comment: Work fine. I thought `##` make no sense with `__VA_ARGS__`, but work.

Comment: You should change the printf("%s\n" to fprintf( stderr, "%s\n" though. For various reasons, most importantly, printf goes to stout which is cached, stderr is not cached out is output straight away.

Comment: Hum.. @Nathan Day. I saw things like this and didn't understand. But if it make things better, I will use :)

Comment: Oh how sweet it is! :)

Comment: Is there a way to make this global. I still get time and application name for other libraries.