# Hide app name from NSLog()

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

I want to modify `NSLog()` so it only shows the current *human readable* timestamp, but no the app name.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517252/clean-nslog-no-timestamp-and-program-name) shows how to remove both the app name and the timestamp in a very simple and elegant way.

Any easy and clean way of suppressing only the app name with macros? I wanted to avoid using an intermediate function with a `NSDateFormatter` object, etc.

Comment: You could just add the timestamp to those macros that you reference in that other question.

Comment: Do you mean by using a NSDateFormatter object within the macros? Or do you mean something else? Note that I want a human-readable timestamp (similar to the one NSLog() shows) not a "raw" one.

Comment: Sure, if the `description` of the `NSDate` isn't to your liking (i.e. that's what it uses if you use `%@` and pass it a `NSDate` object), use date formatter. Use whatever you want.